# ¿Qué es un array de un objeto?

Tags: c++, array

Si creo una clase Asignatura y después en otra clase creo una variable objeto array:

```
class Estudiante{
    string nombre;
    string dni;
    Asignatura num_asignaturas[7]; //Esta variable, ¿qué es lo que contiene realmente?
};

class Asignatura{
    string nombre;
    string codigo;
    int numero_asignaturas;
};
```

¿Qué contiene realmente la variable `Asignatura num_asignaturas[7]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C++ una formación<sup>1</sup> es una colección de objetos del mismo tipo contiguos en memoria, en tu caso:

```
Asignatura num_asignaturas[7];
```

Estás indicando que tendrás siete objetos de tipo `Asignatura` contiguos en memoria, todos estos objetos serán accesibles a través del símbolo `num_asignaturas` contenido en el objeto `Estudiante`.

Dado que la formación `num_asignaturas` es un sub-objeto dentro del objeto `Estudiante`, ésta contribuirá al tamaño total del objeto, así que si esto<sup>2</sup> es tu objeto `Asignatura`:

[image]

Tu objeto `Estudiante` se parecería a esto<sup>2</sup>:

[image]

---

1. También conocida como arreglo o en inglés "*array*".
2. Los tamaños son sólo ilustrativos, no son un reflejo exacto de la realidad.

Answer (score 0):

La variable núm_asignaturas contiene una instancia de la clase Asignatura en cada una de sus 7 celdas. Si no ha sido inicializada cada celda apunta a null.

Para entender el concepto de array debe imaginarte la array cómo una serie de celdas ordenadas a las que puedes acceder directamente mediante un índice válido, un entero, que se ecuentre dentro de los límites del array, marcados por su tamaño.

Así, un array de Asignatura llamado num_asignatura de 7 celdas se crea cómo tu lo has hecho. Los límites del índice serán de 0 para su primera celda  a 6 para la ultima (una menos que su tamaño ). En c++ muchos otros lenguajes el 0 es el primer elemento de las arrays.

Un ejemplo:

Asigatuna num_asignaturas [2];

Y tenemos dos intancias de la clase asignatura que se llaman álgebra y cálculo y num_asignaturas[0] = álgebra y 
num_asignaturas [1]=calculo y un índice entero i(int i).

Para acceder a la asignatura álgebra mediante un índice enten solo debemos hacer i=0 y solicitar a la array la instància en su primera celda mediante num_asignaturas [0]

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Un array (arreglo) de un objeto, es simplemente un conjunto de datos que se almacenan en memoria.

Para entender lo que es un arreglo de objeto, vamos a una capa "menor", la de arreglo de variable.

El array se compone en C++ del tipo de dato (int, double, etc...), el nombre de la variable y su cantidad de elementos.

Para "diferenciar" y acceder a cada uno de los datos almacenados dentro de esa variable, se utiliza el índice el cual está entre corchetes [ ] y va desde 0 en adelante según el orden de los datos ingresados de izquierda a derecha, en este caso sería así el índice:

```
"ruby" = [0]
"c++" = [1]
"php" = [2]
"python" = [3]
```

Por lo tanto al establecer que...

```
lenguaje_de_programacion[3] // el resultado sería "python".
```

PD: En cada lenguaje la sintaxis es diferente, este es solo un ejemplo.

Cabe mencionar que en c++ existen arrays del tipo unidimensional, bidimensional y multidimensional.

**En el caso de los arrays de objetos:**

Los objetos son como tal variables por lo que pueden disponerse de la misma forma en arrays como variables comunes con la diferencia de que en este caso se almacenarán objetos de una o más clases en el array (arreglo).

Cabe mencionar que la sintaxis del array puede cambiar entre un lenguaje a otro pero el fundamento es el mismo.

Espero haberte sido útil. Saludos!